# Linked Google Sheet in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides-api, google-slides

I embedded a google sheet into google slides.  When in slides, the spreadsheet is 5 lines too long for the slide page (8.5 x 11).  I can resize the width of the spreadsheet, but can't get resize the length.  Any suggestions? I need to keep it as a sheet and not an image.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the table height of the table inserted from Google Spreadsheet to Google Slides.

  - From `I can resize the width of the spreadsheet, but can't get resize the length. Any suggestions?`, I understood that `width` and `length` you are thinking are the table width and table height, respectively.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, unfortunately, when the table height is tried to manually reduce, it cannot be directly changed. Because I think that the minimum row height depends on the font size of the cell text. When the font size of the cell text is reduced, each row height can be reduced. But, in this case, when this process is manually run, I thought that it's hard work. So, in this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using a Google Apps Script. I thought that using a script would be suitable for such a process.

There is the method of `setHeight` in Class Table of Slides service. But, unfortunately, it seems that this cannot be directly used. Fortunately, when Slides API is used, the table height (row height) can be resized. And, as an important point, the minimum row height depends on the font size of the cell text. So, it is required to reduce both the font size of the cell text and the row height.

When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Slides. This sample script uses Slides API. So, please enable Slides API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

As the sample situation, this script supposes that a table is manually copied from Google Spreadsheet to the 1st slide of Google Slides. So when you test this script, please copy the cells from Google Spreadsheet to the 1st slide of Google Slides and run the function.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const fontSize = 5; // pt: Please set this value for your actual situation.
  const rowHeight = 10; // pt: Please set this value for your actual situation.

  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  const slide = s.getSlides()[0];
  const table = slide.getTables()[0];
  for (let r = 0; r < table.getNumRows(); r++) {
    const row = table.getRow(r);
    for (let c = 0; c < row.getNumCells(); c++) {
      row.getCell(c).getText().getTextStyle().setFontSize(fontSize);
    }
  }
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ updateTableRowProperties: { tableRowProperties: { minRowHeight: { magnitude: rowHeight, unit: "PT" } }, objectId: table.getObjectId(), fields: "minRowHeight" } }] }, s.getId());
}
```

- When this script is run, the table height of a table of the 1st page of Google Slides is reduced.

#### Result:

When this script is used, the following situation is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateTableRowPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updatetablerowpropertiesrequest)